# symfony default url to 404-not found

Tags: php, symfony, url

I don't have any knowledge about symfony,

But my client ask me to do some do some task on symfony peoject,
what i want validate url

> http://siteurl/faq

should work fine but when user enter some unwanted url like

> http://siteurl/faq123

it is redirecting some other page.

I want to redirect url to 404-not found page

Comment: Is the boss paying you to do this?  If so I'll be glad to sub contract the problem.  If not then start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: Non-existant routes (as your `/faq123` would probably be) automatically already generate a 404 in symfony, there should be no need to do anything at all. You can customize the look of it, see [How to Customize Error Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html).

Answer (score 0):

I f you want to redirect to 404 page , try this,

```
if (!$url) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Sorry,Page doesn't exist');
}
```

Don't forget the use statement

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

Comment: Interesting.  And where exactly in a standard Symfony application would you put this line?